# How do I add a product to OpenCart from an external site?

Tags: php, html, opencart

I need to add a product to the shopping cart from a website to ocart. I was trying the following code. All I get is "shopping cart empty" after the user clicks the submit button.

I made sure that the product id = 40 does exist. thansk for any help

```
<form action="http://***.com/purchase/index.php?route=checkout/cart" id="personalVirtualPrivateServerForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="40">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="2">
<input type="submit" alt="Order Now" title=" value="Order Now">
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP code?

Comment: what php code? shouldn't this be enough to make a post to the shopping cart?

Comment: What version of OpenCart are you running?

Comment: @daker it's version 1.5.6

Comment: Ok, then your html is fine. What are the server responding with? Is your OpenCart installed under `/purchase` (normally it's just http://yoursite/index.php?route=checkout/cart)? Do you have any `rewrite rules` on the server that may break your url?

Comment: @daker thanks for the reply! ocart is installed under /purchase. when the form is submitted the shopping site is shown but always "cart is empty" so the site loads, but no product gets added to the cart. I checked that product_id=40 does exist too.

Comment: Ok. What you need to do is debug the http post reqest sent to OpenCart. Try adding print_r($_POST) on /purchase/index.php and track down what is happening.

Comment: @daker thanks! I added that and this is the output in the browser: Array ( [product_id] => 40 [quantity] => 2 )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43059/discussion-between-daker-and-user2588945)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form action should be

```
http://***.com/purchase/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add
           mind this particular action being called -^^^^
```

However I think this won't work as the method called `ControllerCheckoutCart::add()` is expected to work with AJAX request returning the JSON response. So if You submit a form to this URL instead of shopping cart being displayed it will display only the JSON response.

Instead of direct submitting the form You should make sure it is submitted by jQuery AJAX after the submit button was clicked. Then You can redirect the user to the shopping cart on success. Here is possible solution, make sure to fill in the real domain. It is not tested. Place this script on the page where the form is present (supposes jQuery is linked to the site):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#personalVirtualPrivateServerForm input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://.../index.php?route=checkout/cart/add'
            data: 'product_id=' + $('form#personalVirtualPrivateServerForm input[name="product_id"]').val() + '&quantity=' + $('form#personalVirtualPrivateServerForm input[name="quantity"]').val(),
            success: function(json) {
                window.location = 'http://.../index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! do I have to put that code in an .onlick in the form submit action? and if so, should the form tag look like <form> instead of  <form action="http://****.com/index.php/?route=checkout/cart" method="post"> ?

Comment: The event You should listen to is already written in the code - it's the form's submit button *click* event - just paste this whole jQuery code into Your template and give it a try. It doesn't matter whether You specify the `<form>` or `<form action="...">` as it has no influence on the javascript nor AJAX request... Just make sure the ID of the form is intact (or change it in the jQuery as well).

Comment: that's great! it now adds with a {"success":"Success: You have added Product 40<\/a> to your shopping cart<\/a>!","total":"1 item(s) - \u00a15.40"} it doesn't redirect to the shopping cart though after the success: function(json) {
                window.location = 'http://.../index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            } is called. any idea why that might be? I put                    console.log('add success'); after the window.location code but the page changes too fast to see if that exectuted or not. thanks again for the help by the way

Answer (score 2):

First off, you are using `index.php?route=checkout/cart` which is the controller to show the cart page. This does not actually add any product to the cart.

I'd approach your problem by either:

1. *shadyyx* solution seems good. You may run into cross-domain policy issues though. Also you will always have to make sure you are using same protocol (https/http) otherwise browsers will block you. This can be frustrating.
2. My prefered solution (and much more robust!) will be to extend the cart controller on your site with a custom function that that receives a GET url (instead of POST).

Something like

```
 index.php?route=checkout/cart/addFromUrl&product_id=xx.
```

By doing so, you can simply link to this url from any site and all you'll have to change is the `product_id` in the url. You will not have to use [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) which can be great at situations where you don't have access to the code on the referees side (like an affiliate marketing i.e). It will also be much easier to maintain since your code will be centralized and edited in 1 location vs having to edit it on multiple referring sites.

The actual function will look something like this

```
 public function addFromUrl() {
    $product_id = isset($this->request->get('product_id')) ? $this->request->get('product_id') : '';
      if ($product_id) {
     //your code (you can use $this->add i.e
     //after adding the product, you will need to redirect to the product page or to the cart page
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps!
Yani