# Add Product Options to Cart via AJAX and <form> | Opencart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart

This is my first ever question here so any help would be appreciated. I've found a great deal of related information but nothing which exactly fits the bill.

I'm trying to add a product with its various options to the cart via an HTML form and AJAX. Adding the product itself was the first obstacle but it now seems like a bit of a hollow victory.

My form looks like this: (there are more products in the list but I have redacted to save space)

```
<form action="http://[site_url].com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add/" id="quickQuoteForm" method="post">
<h3>Select your course</h3>
<div class="quickPriceRow1 row1">
  <label>Choose a course</label>
  <select class="quickPriceSelect" name="product_id" rel="1">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please choose...</option>
    <option name="product_id" value="50">Intensive General English - 15 hours per week</option>
    <option name="product_id" value="51">Intensive General English Course + Consolidation English/Exam Preparation Workshops (20 hours per week)</option>
  </select>
```

Then, contained in the same form, I have the Product Options like so:

```
<label>Choose a start date</label>
<select name="start_date" class="quickPriceSelect2" rel="2" id="start_date">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please choose...</option>

    <option name="option[5]" value="49">Monday July 28</option>
    <option name="option[5]" value="50">Monday August 04</option>
    <option name="option[5]" value="51">Monday August 11</option>
    <option name="option[5]" value="52">Monday August 18</option>
          etc...
 </select>
```

Now, I'm not 100% I've got the "name=..." right but I've tried both 'name="option[5]"' and 'name="option_id[5]"' with no change. The [5] I took from the 'option_description' table and 'option_id' column and the value="50" from the 'option_value_description' table and 'option_value_id' column.

Thanks to this thread [How do I add a product to OpenCart from an external site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546767/how-do-i-add-a-product-to-opencart-from-an-external-site/20548484#20548484) (and a little tinkering) I've got the product adding to the cart no problem, but the options are stumping me completely.

My jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quickQuoteForm button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://[site_url].com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add/',
            data: 'product_id=' + $('.quickPriceSelect').val() + '&quantity=1' + '&product_option_id=' + $('.quickPriceSelect2').val() + '&product_option_id=' + $('.quickPriceSelect3').val(),
            success: function(json) {
                window.location = 'http://[site_url].com/index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it'd be a massive help, thank you.

**## UPDATE ##**

Ok, so I'm no further on with it but I have changed my JS to match what I found in the product.tpl files (both Default and the theme I'm using; Acceptus). I now have:

```
<script>
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('select[name="product_id"], select[name="option[5]"], select[name="option[13]"]'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] +     </span>');
            }
        }
    } 

    if (json['success']) {
        $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/acceptus/image/icons/remove/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

        $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

        $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
    }   

        if (json['success']) {
            window.location = 'http://studioamanchester.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart';
        }
    }
});
});
</script>'
```

Again, it's adding the product but none of the options. I've tried on the default theme and installed the site locally to test it but still nothing. Is there anything else to try?

Comment: When I implemented opencart, this was already a feature.  What version are you using?  Is the cart online, can you send a link to it?

Comment: Sorry, and it's up at: http://studioamanchester.com/ under 'BOOK'

Also it's only up on the English version.

Thanks

Comment: I do not get you problem as **this is already implemented in OpenCart since version 1.3.x** (when I first came to OpenCart, which was fair 7 years ago!). If it is not working in your installation you should pay attention to the modules/extensions/themes you might recently install that may brake this default behavior. If it is possible (and the default theme is not damaged by your changes), change the theme back to default (in administration) and try to add a product with options set to a cart. You should see it's working just fine. Seeing you struggling with adding product to cart is weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your JS code I can see some errors in the AJAX request itself:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://[site_url].com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add/',
//                  there should be no slash at the end of route  ---^
        data: 'product_id=' + $('.quickPriceSelect').val() + '&quantity=1' + '&product_option_id=' + $('.quickPriceSelect2').val() + '&product_option_id=' + $('.quickPriceSelect3').val(),
// if you send more 'product_option_id' properties, all of them will be overwritten by the last value in the end...
        success: function(json) {
            window.location = 'http://[site_url].com/index.php?route=checkout/cart';
        }
    });
```

We are missing your controller code but let's expect you didn't change it. In this case the POST data is completely incorrect since the cart controller requires to receive product options in `option` array with the `option_id` as key and `production_option_value` as value.

The request should contain POST data like this:

```
option[208]     test
option[209]     adsgsdadas
option[217]     3
option[219]     2011-02-20
option[220]     2011-02-20 22:25
option[221]     22:25
option[222]     
option[223][]   10
product_id      42
quantity        2
```

Since you are completely changing the POST that is sent to the server it is understandable that you think it is not possible. Instead of reinventing the wheel you should now focus to fix your code so that it send the AJAX POST request in this way (copied from the default `product.tpl` template):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                }
            }
        } 

        if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
        }   
    }
});
```

The line containing the `data` has it all - simply it finds any form field within the given `div` and pack it's `name:value` to the POST (while the option's names are `option[<option_id>]`).

Comment: Could you check the updated JS I've posted? See if I've missed anything?\

Comment: Did you change also some code in the `CheckoutCartController` or in the system library `Cart`?

Comment: I had done yes, but have now replaced the entire Controller directory with a fresh copy from 1.5.6.1. I have kept a changed Controller > Common > header.php which brings the information pages into the menu. But that couldn't effect it could it? I've tried adding the product options with a clean header.php and no difference.

Comment: OK, now install a fresh new OpenCart and try it with it. Or just go to demo.opencart.com and try it there...

Comment: Right, ok. So I have it almost working but think my new problem may be out of the scope of this question. 
I copied the relevant jQuery from the bottom of product.tpl and added it to the bottom of information.tpl and the data is being captured and sent to the cart. Success!
However, it looks like I was passing the wrong ids in the form itself. Looking at the select options on the product pages I am getting different values for each product.
Should the option ids not remain the same for each product if that product has been given the same option?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not get your question. I am surprised that in the ed you are mentioning `information.tpl` because I think we all thought we are talking about the normal product flow. But adding some new functionality (like to information pages) should be mentioned at the start and we would immediately recommend copying contents from `product.tpl` and respective changes in controllers... To your last question - if I understand it correctly, then one option can be assigned to many products while it's ID remains the same through all products. Same applies for option values (and their IDs).

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I should have mentioned that I was trying to create the form on an information page, apologies for the confusion.
That's what I thought about the options but I may be missing something obvious. Am I right in thinking that the '<select name="option[x]">' should come from 'option_id' and the '<option value="x">' should come from the 'option_value_id' fields in the 'option_description' table?

Comment: Most probably yes. Checking in/copying from `product.tpl` should prove/make it right :-)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, you're sending your variables as a query string when you should try sending them as POST variables instead.  This is what the service expects you to send:

```
Request URL:http://studioamanchester.com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add/
Request Method:POST

Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
route:checkout/cart/add/

Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
product_id:51
quantity:1
product_option_id:56
product_option_id:95
```

Try this (not sure about the two properties with the same name, but see if it works):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quickQuoteForm button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting

        var obj = { 
            product_id : $('.quickPriceSelect').val(), 
            quantity : "1", 
            product_option_id : $('.quickPriceSelect2').val(), 
            product_option_id : $('.quickPriceSelect3').val() 
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://[site_url].com/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add/',
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            success: function(json) {
                window.location = 'http://[site_url].com/index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmmm, firstly thank you, but I'm afraid I'm no further along.

I've tried your answer as is but it's now not continuing through to the cart page. It stays on "/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add/" with a success message. It is adding the product although the options aren't being added as the price total remains the same.

I also tried changing quantity = '1' to quantity: '1' as I was getting a syntax error. This continues to the cart page but doesn't add any products. 

I've left it up with the code from your answer if you can see anything I can't.

Comment: @carrdarch The method on your Book page appears to be sending `product_id:52,
start_date:57,
course_length:97,
submit:Book` which is not the same as the expected `product_id:51,
quantity:1,
product_option_id:56,
product_option_id:95`